# Map https to http using Charles "Map Remote"

Tags: charles-proxy

I use Charles Proxy to test out my urls. Charles has a feature that lets you map from one url to another and essentially redirects traffic to a different destination url.

My source url uses https whereas my destination url uses http. I have not been able to get this to work. Does anyone know if this is even possible. Mapping from http to http or from https to https works. Just not from https to http.

Comment: Works fine for me. What issue are you having?